# Neo4j Cypher: Importing nested collection by getting Error: Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character code 99

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nested collection and I add "Data" then foreach "Data" I add its own "Tags". I found unwind for "Data" with foreach for "Tags".
I wanna add person which I import its info from outside of collection manually.

I execute below Cypher query by statements:
I have imitated from: 
[Cypher Import Statement](http://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/) 
AND 
[Cypher Unwind](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/05/31/neo4j-cypher-unwind-vs-foreach/)
I  checked my json via [enter link description here](http://jsonlint.com/) And it is validated.

```
{  "statements": [ {  "statement": " WITH {  "categories":  [ {"dataid" : "11" , "dataname" : "data1" , "datalanguage" : "en" , "datatype" : "type1" ,"content" : "content1" , "tags" : [{"myid" : "11" , "tagid" : 10 , "tagname" : "tag1" }] } , {"dataid" : "22" , "dataname" : "data2" , "datalanguage" : "en" , "datatype" : "type2" ,"content" : "content2" , "tags" : [{"myid" : "22" , "tagid" : 20 , "tagname" : "tag2" }] } ] } AS document  UNWIND document.categories AS category  MERGE (dt:Data {name: category.dataname}) ON CREATE SET dt.id = category.dataid , dt.type = category.datatype , dt.language = category.datalanguage , dt.content = category.datacontent   MERGE (p:Person { name : 'Mahsa' , lastname : 'Mahsa' } ) ON CREATE SET p.id =1 MERGE (p)-[r:owner]->(dt)  FOREACH (mytag IN category.tags |  MERGE (t:Tag {name: mytag.tagname}) ON CREATE SET t.id = mytag.tagid  MERGE (dt)-[r2:tagged { Freq : 12 ]->(t) )" } ] }
```

But it returns as result: (I checked many times for **"Unexpected character"** but I could not find )

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"**Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat**","message":"**Unable to deserialize request: Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries**\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@132e16b; line: 1, column: 48]"}]}
```

I made my nested collection as:

```
string dataCollection2 = "{  \"categories\":  [ {\"dataid\" : \"11\" , \"dataname\" : \"data1\" , \"datalanguage\" : \"en\" , \"datatype\" : \"type1\" ," +
            "\"content\" : \"content1\" , \"tags\" : [{\"myid\" : \"11\" , \"tagid\" : 10 , \"tagname\" : \"tag1\" }] }" +
            " , {\"dataid\" : \"22\" , \"dataname\" : \"data2\" , \"datalanguage\" : \"en\" , \"datatype\" : \"type2\" ," +
            "\"content\" : \"content2\" , \"tags\" : [{\"myid\" : \"22\" , \"tagid\" : 20 , \"tagname\" : \"tag2\" }] } ] }";
var obj1 = JValue.Parse(@"'" + dataCollection2 + "'");
```

I imported my json to http://jsonlint,com and I got it is validated:

```
 {
"categories": [
    {
        "dataid": 11,
        "dataname": "data1",
        "datalanguage": "en",
        "datatype": "type1",
        "content": "content1",
        "tags": [
            {
                "myid": 11,
                "tagid": 10,
                "tagname": "tag1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dataid": 22,
        "dataname": "data2",
        "datalanguage": "en",
        "datatype": "type2",
        "content": "content2",
        "tags": [
            {
                "myid": 22,
                "tagid": 20,
                "tagname": "tag2"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: The json you provided is not legal, starting at `categories`. Are you providing the right string?  (Also, please use 4-character indentation, not `code>` to mark up your data.)

Comment: Thanks @cybersam. I imitated from http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/23/neo4j-loading-json-documents-with-cypher/ because I wanted to extract each category in one raw

Comment: OK, but the data you said is validated does not actually validate.

Comment: @cybersam I added my json at the end of my question plz import it and get the result.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Adding nested collection to neo4j:**

**Firstly:** For having right input to neo4j as parameter I must remove "{
"categories": [ ] }" from the first and the end of json.

**Secondly:** I should put this json as parameter to statement

**Thirdly:** I have to use two "UNWIND and WITH" (instead of using foreach) for separating each row from collection either for parent or for child.

"Foreach" DOES similar to "UNWIND and WITH".
My final collection and query are:

**Collection:**

```
{"id" : 1, "name" : "Data1", "language" : "en", "tags": {"id" : 11, "name": "tag 11" } } ,  {"id" : 2, "name": "Data2" , "tags": [ {"id" : 33, "name": "tag 33"} ,  {"id" : 44, "name": "tag44"} ] }
```

**Query:**

```
{  "statements": [ {  "statement": " UNWIND { datas } AS data  MERGE (p:Person { name : 'God' , lastname : 'God' } ) ON CREATE SET p.id =2 MERGE (d:Data {name: data.name}) ON CREATE SET d.id = data.id  , d.language = data.language   MERGE (p)-[r:owner]->(d)  WITH  d, data.tags AS mytags  UNWIND mytags AS mytag  MERGE (t:Tag {name: mytag.name}) ON CREATE SET t.id = mytag.id  MERGE (d)-[r2:tagged { Freq : 12 } ]->(t) " , "parameters":  { "datas" : [{"id" : 1, "name" : "Data1", "language" : "en", "tags": {"id" : 11, "name": "tag 11" } } ,  {"id" : 2, "name": "Data2" , "tags": [ {"id" : 33, "name": "tag 33"} ,  {"id" : 44, "name": "tag44"} ] }]  }  } ] }
```

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem with the string you are passing to the REST API is that you are not passing a legal Cypher query. Cypher property "maps", which look a bit like JSON, are NOT JSON.

In your case, the important difference is that property *names* must NOT be delimited by double-quotes. Only string property *values* can be delimited by double-quotes.

So, `categories`, `dataId`, `dataName`, etc., must not be surrounded by double-quotes.

You also have a typo near the end of the query. `[r2:tagged { Freq : 12 ]` should be `[r2:tagged { Freq : 12} ]`.

Comment: I checked so many times but I stil have same issues. If you can get answer plz let me know ur neo4j version